# how to std::bind templated function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

1) I have function declared as

```
    template< unsigned ... N, typename ... T2>
    auto Foo(T2 ... args);
```

it works properly when it called for example as

```
double a = Foo<1>(1.0);
```

but doesn't even compile as

```
double a = Foo<1,double>(1.0);
```

Why it so?

2) The actual problem is that neither of the following compiles, so how to `bind` it correctly?

```
 std::function<double(double)> f = std::bind(&Foo<1>,std::placeholders::_1); 
 std::function<double(double)> g = std::bind(&Foo<1,double>,std::placeholders::_1);
```

**Edit**
Thanks to Jonathan Wakely
3) The reason to `std::bind` it comes from

```
class Bar
{
    Bar(std::function<T(T)> &f);
};
```

Comment: lambda it: `std::function<double(double)> f = [] (double d) { return Foo<1>(d); }`

Comment: Use a lambda, but why are you trying to use `std::bind` anyway? Your `bind` expressions would create a callable object that takes a `double` and returns `double`, but that's what the function is already.

Comment: good question! see the edit

Comment: Did you mean maybe `template< unsigned N, typename ... T2>` ? What is N for anyway?

Comment: nope, both variadic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only trying to cover `Why it so?` part assuming you are getting smth like

> note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified
>   argument for 1st template parameter

[n4618](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4618.pdf) 14.1.11 says:

> A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed
>   by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be
>   deduced from the parameter-type-list (8.3.5) of the function template
>   or has a default argument (14.8.2).

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) alludes similarly:

> In a function template, the template parameter pack may appear earlier
>   in the list provided that all following parameters can be deduced from
>   the function arguments

Your first parameter pack is not among function arguments so its impossible to deduce it properly

Comment: well, that explains but little bit surprising, because in this specific case it should be possible to distinct between non-type from type parameter pack.

Comment: Interesting but I don't understand why `Foo<1>(1.0);` compile: the first parameter pack isn't in deduced from the function arguments. Anyway: 14.1.11 is about a parameter pack followed by a single template parameter (not pack); the OP ask about a parameter (not type) pack followed by another parameter (type) pack; maybe I'm wrong but it seems to me a little different.

Comment: @max66 I think in that context "followed by single type" or "pack of types" does not matter, but I could be very well wrong

Comment: @OlegBogdanov - I see... Well, I love variadic templates but sometimes they causes me terrible headaches.